# Adding a limit to a remind command | discord.py

Tags: discord.py

So I've got a simple remind script asyncio, and i was wondering if it was possible to add a limit to how much a reminder time could be, I was thinking around 60 minutes. Here is my code:

```py
@client.command()
async def remind(ctx, mins : int, reminder):
    embed=discord.Embed(title='Reminder set', description=f"{ctx.author.mention}, I have set a reminder for {mins} minutes with the reminder being {reminder}", colour=discord.Colour.blurple())
    embed.timestamp = ctx.message.created_at
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)

    counter = 0
    while counter <= int(mins):
        counter += 1
        await asyncio.sleep(60)

        if counter == int(mins):
            await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.mention}, your reminder for {reminder} with a time of {mins} minutes has gone off.")
            break
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to set the limit of `mins` to **60**, you could just check if `mins` > **60** before starting your `while` loop.

```py
@client.command()
async def remind(ctx, mins : int, reminder):

    if mins > 60:
        # Stop here if mins > 60
        await ctx.send("The limit for a reminder is 60 minutes!")
        return

    embed=discord.Embed(title='Reminder set', description=f"{ctx.author.mention}, I have set a reminder for {mins} minutes with the reminder being {reminder}", colour=discord.Colour.blurple())
    embed.timestamp = ctx.message.created_at
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)

    counter = 0
    while counter <= int(mins):
        counter += 1
        await asyncio.sleep(60)

        if counter == int(mins):
            await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.mention}, your reminder for {reminder} with a time of {mins} minutes has gone off.")
            break
```